# Access violation when loading dll

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++, dll, access-violation

A plain C application compiles fine on MSVC6, but when running, it raises an Access violation.

When running the app in WinDbg, I get the AV error raised when loading rasadhlp.dll (a windows file).

**Question:** What could possibly cause an access violation when loading a windows dll?

I'm used to working on the various nixes rather than windows, so there might be something really obvious that I'm missing.

```
[...]
ModLoad: 77920000 77a13000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
ModLoad: 76fc0000 76fc6000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasadhlp.dll
  (f38.a08): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
  First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
  This exception may be expected and handled.
  eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=0049f8f0 esi=0049f8f0 edi=00000000
  eip=7c918fea esp=0012fbdc ebp=0012fc50 iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na pe nc
  cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010286
  ntdll!RtlpWaitForCriticalSection+0x5b:
  7c918fea ff4010          inc     dword ptr [eax+10h]  ds:0023:00000010=????????
0:000> g
  (f38.a08): Access violation - code c0000005 (!!! second chance !!!)
  eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=0049f8f0 esi=0049f8f0 edi=00000000
  eip=7c918fea esp=0012fbdc ebp=0012fc50 iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na pe nc
  cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000286
  ntdll!RtlpWaitForCriticalSection+0x5b:
  7c918fea ff4010          inc     dword ptr [eax+10h]  ds:0023:00000010=????????
```

Note: The app is compiled on win2k, tested on XP. (which, for various weird reasons, can't be changed right now...)

**[edit]:** program trace:

```
ntdll!RtlpWaitForCriticalSection+0x5b
ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x46
msvcrt!vprintf+0x18
intl!libintl_vfprintf+0xa8
intl!libintl_fprintf+0x1f
image00400000+0x6239
MSCTF!DllGetClassObject+0x1de9
ntdll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey+0x7ec8
ntdll!RtlInitializeSListHead+0x115c0
ntdll!iswdigit+0x339
ntdll!LdrGetProcedureAddress+0x4b
image00400000+0x626f4
```

**[edit 2]:** I know that the exception is first caught by the debugger, and that this is completely normal. You'll notice in the log that I manually skip over the first-chance exception, and force it to rise into my program. I'm wondering about the origin of such an error, rather than the handling.

Comment: Can you trace your program's execution? does the crash happen before the entry to main?

Comment: also, are you compiling your program with a static or dynamic runtime?

Comment: I've got a sneaking suspicion that you are mixing two versions of the runtime, which may cause some interesting issues. You should try compiling your program against the static runtime

Comment: Hey Hasturkun. That sounds pretty reasonable. I think it's static linking, but since this is inherited code, let me make sure...

Comment: This is environmental, the stack trace sure doesn't point to your code.  msctf.dll is a red flag, go into Control Panel + Regional and Language options and disable the language bar.  Or let the machine slip out of a 4th story window.

Comment: @Hans: I seriously considered the latter solution...

Answer (score 2):

See [Microsoft support - First and second chance exception handling](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carmelop/2012/11/06/first-chance-exception-vs-second-chance-exception/)

> It is a common practice to use SEH as a signaling mechanism. Some
>   application programming interfaces (APIs) register an exception
>   handler in anticipation of a failure condition that is expected to
>   occur in a lower layer.
>
> When an exception is raised, the handler may correct or ignore the
>   condition rather than allow a failure to propagate up through
>   intervening layers. This is very useful in complex environments such
>   as networks where partial failures are expected and it is not
>   desirable to fail an entire operation just because one of several
>   optional parts failed. In this case, the exception can be handled so
>   that the application does not recognize that an exception has
>   occurred.
>
> However, if the application is being debugged, the debugger sees all
>   exceptions before the program does. This is the distinction between
>   the first and second chance exception: the debugger gets the first
>   chance to see the exception (hence the name). If the debugger allows
>   the program execution to continue and does not handle the exception,
>   the program will see the exception as usual. If the program does not
>   handle the exception, the debugger gets a second chance to see the
>   exception. In this latter case, the program normally would crash if
>   the debugger were not present.
>
> If you do not want to see the first chance exception in the debugger,
>   you should disable first chance exception handling for the specific
>   exception code. Otherwise, when the first chance exception occurs, you
>   may need to instruct the debugger to pass on the exception to the
>   program to be handled as usual.

Comment: I may give you a -1, No sane person uses an Access Violation for internal signalling.

Comment: This could equally be flagged for not being an answer.

Comment: Well, "Access Violation" is a common "first-chance exception". This problem is generated when a 'debugger' receives an exception from the running program -- The program generates an exception, and before the program handles it, the debugger will receive "First-chance exception", then, the exception should be handled by the program itself. If the program doesn't handle it, the debugger will receive "second-chance/last-chance exception", and end the program. I guess the article from Microsoft explains it well.

Comment: Another example [First-chance exception - Access Violation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/250563/en-us)

Comment: @Stan: I know that the first is normally caught by the debugger, And you'll notice in the log that I manualy jump over the first chance. What I'm wondering is why it happens in the first place, especially just after loading rasadhlp.dll, which a windows dll.
Its also true that Access violations should **NEVER** be used as a signal. This isn't a catching problem, but an origin problem.

Answer (score 2):

Access violations in `RtlpWaitForCriticalSection` when loading a library, is typically caused by the library trying to use LoadLibrary or code outside of kernel32.dll, in DllMain since the OS holds a "loader lock" while calling that routine.